# Модель Django string array

Tags: django, строки, backend, model, модель-данных

Мне нужно создать поле типа ***string***, но при этом чтобы это был массив (example:string[]).

**P.S.** в backend'е совсем новичок, поэтому буду рад любым статьям и объяснениям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с полем типа массив вам понадобится postresql. Эта БД имеет хорошую поддержку со стороны Django.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models


class People(models.Model):
    hobbies = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
```

Сперва инициализируем сам тип поля - ArrayField.  А затем указываем обязательный для него параметр - тип хранимых значений ( в данном примере CharField ).

PS: в большинстве случае лучше использовать отношения ManyToMany вместо ArrayField